# Duda con sistema de tickets php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de tickets para reportes que hacen los usuarios. Hasta la inserción de datos todo es correcto. La cosa es, he hecho dos tablas diferentes, una llamada remedy donde se guardan los datos de el ticket y otra de usuarios donde tiene su información. Mi pregunta es, ¿como ligo ese ticket al usuario? en la tabla remedy, ¿pongo IdUsuario como relación? y si es así, ¿Como sería el select para que ese usuario viera el ticket que ha abierto?

Comment: @Flowcow tu pregunta es susceptible de ser cerrada tal y como está. Lo lógico sería que la información del ticket contenga el id del usuario que lo genera, y con ese dato relacionar ambas tablas con un para hacer un select con join es muy sencillo, intentalo y si tienes problemas con la query y el resultado muestralo junto con la estructura de tus tablas para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Para insertar debería hacer lo mismo?

Comment: Al insertar sólo necesitarías rellenar el campo id_usuario en el registro del ticket, además de la información que ya registrabas, el join sólo es para seleccionar los datos del usuario y relacionarlo con sus tickets